# Magento 2: How to get visitors data

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, magento-2.1, dependency-injection

I want to get visitor Id in my custom block for getting product view history of non logged in customer

```
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor $customerVisitor
   ){
     $this->_customerVisitor = $customerVisitor;
   }

    .....
    echo $visitorId = $this->_customerVisitor->getId();exit;
   ....
```

but i am not getting any value how to get visitor id?

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. Did you declare `protected $_customerVisitor;` in your class ?

Comment: NO i don't, can you tell me if i am not declare `protected $_customerVisitor;` this than what happened?

Answer (score 2):

According to what you told me in the comments, **the problem comes from the fact that you didn't declare the protected variable to store `\Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor`**

So in your case **when you call `$this->_customerVisitor` it doesn't work because this variable is not declared.**

You need to add the following code before the `__construct()` method declaration to fix your issue:

```
protected $_customerVisitor;
```

Comment: i declare variable before __construct() but i am not getting visitor id

Comment: @Newbie are you sure your block is getting called ?

Comment: yes it my block is getting called

Comment: @Newbie well I'm not sure what's wrong here in that case

Answer (score 1):

Its your Full page cache. If you disable the full page cache, you will get the visitor data. It seems kind of Magento Bug, which is related to recently view products block.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor` class to get visitor data

```
protected $_visitor;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor $visitor
    ...
) {
    $this->_visitor = $visitor;
}

public function getVisitors()
{
    $visitors = $this->_visitor->getCollection();
    print_r($visitors); //Print visitors data
}
```