# How to get cartId of a guest-user in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to use external software (widget written in javascript attached to Magento) to add products to cart through API (POST request @ `/rest/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items)`.

For this, I need cartId for guest-user (non authenticated user). I tried to make a POST request to

```
/rest/V1/guest-carts
```

but this request creates *new* cart, but I need to get current cartId of visitor somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: you are suppose to get it after your first post request

Comment: @magefms Which request? When I do POST @ /rest/V1/guest-carts it gives me fresh cartId, but when I after add product to basket manually, then Magento creates another cartId.

Comment: so you are adding product items both from API post endpoint and manually?

Comment: Yes! Sometimes client may use magento standard way and sometimes client can use my custom software (embedded widget written in javascript) to add product to basket (this should be through API I belive)

Comment: hmm that's a bit complicated unless the user is logged in otherwise every time the guest user add items from different platform (magento and your custom software) to the cart it will generate new cart id.

Comment: Yess, I think so :) That's why my software needs to know cart ID associated with with guest user :)

Comment: maybe this post would help you get started https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134192/magento-2-how-to-get-visitors-data

Comment: I had this issue in M1 - we had a seperate application that created a new custom product via REST, but it was not possible to add the product to the users cart, as the REST session was different to the browser session and thus was the cart. I simply wrote a module that had a redirect route which would add a given product ID to the browsers session cart and redirect the user to this. I couldn't find a quicker way to do it back then.

Comment: I created a custom script to be called as soon as the website is loaded to check if quote id exists, if doesn't then my script finds random active product and adds to cart and immediately remove it too, This creates a active quote for the user and that cartId/quoteId can be used to add product to cart using RestAPI